# Build time optimization C++ Microsoft Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, compilation

I am trying to optimize my build time.
I have relatively small project and I placed majority of headers into a precompiled header.

Nevertheless in build log I have 7000 functions that are rebuilt every time. I am wondering where they come from. Maximum I have 100 functions, no templates, therefore I would like to ask what can take extra time to compile and where those 7000 come from?

Every time I add a new function the compilation times increases from 4 seconds to 8 seconds.
If I just change existing variable or add new variable inside function the time is again 4 seconds.

This is what I see as the main change after new code is added:

```
1> Previous IPDB and IOBJ mismatch, fall back to full compilation. 
1> All 7005 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
```

Is there a possibility to print header names where those functions coming from?

[image]

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: joinery_solver_viewer, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Build started 5/7/2022 11:11:55 PM.
1>Target InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "x64\Release\joinery_.a924c778.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>Target ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  joinery_solver_viewer.cpp
1>Target Link:
1>  Generating code
1>  0 of 7005 functions ( 0.0%) were compiled, the rest were copied from previous compilation.
1>    0 functions were new in current compilation
1>    0 functions had inline decision re-evaluated but remain unchanged
1>  Finished generating code
1>  joinery_solver_viewer.vcxproj -> C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\Python\compas_wood\net\x64\Release\joinery_solver_viewer.exe
1>Target FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "x64\Release\joinery_.a924c778.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "x64\Release\joinery_.a924c778.tlog\joinery_solver_viewer.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    0 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.99
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: 2022 ;) My mistake

Comment: You are likely calling some library functions that are inlined in the headers. And they call other standard library functions, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to list all called headers?

Comment: There is a `/showIncludes` option for that. And you will be surprised!

Comment: Wow... I see the list

Comment: @BoP Do .cpp file reduce the compilation time as well? Still it did not explain the 7000 functions, it still seams small number of my own code

Comment: Specially this lines worries me, every time I change the code I see that: 
1>  Previous IPDB and IOBJ mismatch, fall back to full compilation.
1>  All 7005 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.

Comment: Maybe due to some template code? You can generate the code in debug mode and check the generated symbols.

Comment: @BoP _There is a /showIncludes option for that_ that sounds incredibly useful, TVM.

Comment: _Time Elapsed 00:00:03.99_ Doesn't sound _too_ bad...

Comment: @I am talking about 7.99 the moment I add a new function in code it increases by 4 seconds